# Can react-select pass nesting data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm maintaining the code from others. The web is currently using react-select@1.3.0

And I have to pass the data to the backend which the data type is limited to the array value, eg: `["1", "2", "3" ...]`. Even, the array containing objects like this, eg: `[{a:"1"}, {b:"2"}, {c:"3"} ...]` are not allowed.

So, using the way react-select pass data, the structure is

```
[
  { label: "one", value: "1" },
  { lable: "two", value: "2" },
  { label: "three", value: "3" },
  // ...
]
```

I'm now passing the value I got from react-select to the temp place at state, and structure the data again when users hit the submit button, however, it seems not efficiency enough?

Below is the simple version of real code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from "react-select";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tempAr: [ ],
      selectedValues: [ ]
    }
  }

  onChange(values) {
    this.setState({values});
  }

  submit() {
     const newValue = this.state.tempArr.map(i=>i.value)
     this.setState({selectedValue:newValue})
   }

  render() {

    const branch_list = [{label:"Taoyuan Branch", value:"001"}, 
                         {lable:"Pintung Branch", value:"002"}, 
                         {label:"Kaoshiung Branch", value:"003"} ...] 

    return (
      <div className="App">
            <Select 
                multi 
                options={branch_list} 
                onChange={onChange}
                value={this.state.tempArr}
                removeSelected={true}
                hideSelectedOptions={false}
              />     
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Is there any straightforward way to skip the process of restructuring data?

Comment: On submit you can directly use Object.values(this.state.tempArr) to get only values. You dont need to map tempArr to form new array

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Thanks for replying. But my main question is how to skip the process and set state directly?